# Filtered List Unable to use .contains

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am trying to turn my list view into a filtered list view. I found instructions on stack overflow, but the thread is locked so i can not comment on it to ask this question. For some reason when i type the expression:

```
filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filterUID));
```

the s.contains(filteredUID)); does not work due to error

> Error:(65, 51) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   contains(java.lang.String)   location: variable s of type
>   Controllers.ModelTable

full code:

```
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        filter_uid.textProperty().addListener(obs ->{
            String filterUID = filter_uid.getText();
            if (filterUID == null || filterUID.length() == 0){
                filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> true);
            }else {
                filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filterUID));
            }
        });
```

Definitions :

```
@FXML public TableView<ModelTable> taskManagerView;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_UID;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_Date;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_CreatedBy;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_Category;
    @FXML public TableColumn<ModelTable, String> col_Task;

        @FXML
        TextField filter_uid;
        @FXML
        TextField filter_created;
        @FXML
        ChoiceBox filtered_choice;
        @FXML
        DatePicker filter_date;



    ObservableList<ModelTable> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    FilteredList<ModelTable> filteredOblist = new FilteredList<>(oblist, s -> true);
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the type of this `filter_uid`?

Comment: @FXML
        TextField filter_uid;

Comment: What is the type of this `filteredOblist`?

Comment: I edited the original post, please see.

Comment: From where does this `ModelTable` come? It says `ModelTable cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. and unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Model table is a seperate class that just has one constructor. public class ModelTable {

    String UID, Date, CreatedBy, Category, Task;

    public ModelTable(String UID, String date, String createdBy, String category, String task) {
        this.UID = UID;
        Date = date;
        CreatedBy = createdBy;
        Category = category;
        Task = task;
    }

Comment: I can't see, where does `filteredOblist` come from

Comment: that said: the error tells you exactly what's wrong: ModelTable does not have a method _contains_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work your `ModelTable` class should have `contains` method like so,

```
public boolean contains(String uuid) {
        return UID.equals(uuid);
}
```

Conversely if you need to have different filter strategies as stated in your comment I would hand off that responsibility to the client by merely taking it off from the `ModelTable` class. Just write a predicate by accessing different fields from the `ModelTable` as desired. Here's how the two predicates looks after deleting the `contains` method from `ModelTable` class.

```
filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.UID.equals(filterUID));

filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.CreatedBy.startsWith(filterCreated));
```

The bottom line is that your client has to provide the filtering strategy since it varies depending on the context.

Comment: I am now trying to define another filter text field. I created a new method in model table called  public boolean containsCreated(String cCreated)  and use this function (exactly same as for UID) to send string to this method, but the filter does not work. I get no errors but whenever i type anything my table view has no data to show.

Comment: filter_created.textProperty().addListener(obs ->{
            String filterCreated = filter_created.getText();
            if (filterCreated == null || filterCreated.length() == 0){
                filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> true);
            }else {
                filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.containsCreated (filterCreated));
            }
        });

Comment: what is the type of `filter_created`?

Comment: Everything is the same, it's an fxml text field @FXML
        TextField filter_created;

Comment: Your method should be `contains` not `containsCreated`. Change it like this: `filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filterCreated));` It's just a typo.

Comment: But what should i then return in the `public boolean contains (String a)` if i want to both filter "UID" and "Created" right now this method returns `return UID.equals(a);`

Comment: Hello, I have now changed it to your second suggestion without the contains method. UID works as before, but created by does not. I basically have a list of tasks with users in created by field such as "Tom , John" whenever i type T or t or J/j the table shows " no content in table. `filteredOblist.setPredicate(s -> s.CreatedBy.equals(filterCreated) );`

Comment: In this case a simple equality check wouldn't work. You may have to do something like this. `s.CreatedBy.startsWith(filterCreated)`. `Predicate` takes a `ModelTable` as it's input and returns a `boolean`. You can alter it the way you want.